# Nuget 3.0 error on azure deployment

Tags: azure, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I have a VS2015 project that I have successfully deployed on Azure (via Github) as a web app.
However, after some offline updates, when I deploy, i get the error

`The 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60717.93'."`

Is nuget 3.0 installed on the web app servers? And how can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reverting the `System.Net.Http 4.0.0` package to an older version, that works with NuGet version 2.8.60717.93.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet doesn't go on the the app server, it goes on the build server.  Make sure your build server has the latest NuGet client.  See this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279970/system-net-http-4-0-0-package-requires-nuget-client-version-3-0-or-above).

Comment: Still the same question, how do I access Nuget 3.0 on azure's build servers?

Comment: Have you updated VS2015 to latest NuGet Package Manager in Extensions and Updates?

Comment: The project is functioning well locally, I only have a problem when deploying on Azure...